# How to work with user input in PHP in a type-safe way

Tags: php, types

I'm trying to implement handling user input (originating in HTTP request in JSON format) and assigning it into typed properties using classes in PHP.

Lets say I have a JSON payload like this:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "qux"
}
```

but the `foo` is nullable, so a valid payload is also this:

```json
{
  "foo": null,
  "baz": "qux"
}
```

and we're actually dealing with a HTTP `PATCH` request so a partial payload like this is also valid:

```json
{
  "baz": "qux"
}
```

So the value of `foo` can be: `string`, `null` or it won't exist.

Now when it comes to having a class for this structure:

```php
class FooRequest
{
    public ?string $foo;
    public string $bar;
}
```

which will need to be translated into another `DTO` structure:

```php
class FooDTO
{
    public ?string $foo;
}
```

So when I'm working with the actual code, I'm using `symfony/http-foundation` to deal with Request and Response.

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$fooPayload = new FooRequest();
foreach ($request->toArray() as $propertyName => $value) {
    $fooPayload->$propertyName = $value;
}
```

So the `FooRequest` has all the data assigned properly. But when it comes to deciding whether the property is `null`, has a value of `string` or is not provided at all is determined by the property being `initialized`, `null` or `string`.

[Code example](https://3v4l.org/QePEE)

When I want to take the next step and assign the value to the `DTO` class, the only suitable way I see in PHP is using [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.isinitialized.php) (I previously tried `property_exists` or `isset`):

```php
$fooDTO = new FooDTO();
$p = new ReflectionProperty(FooRequest::class, 'foo');
if ($p->isInitialized($fooPayload)) {
    $fooDTO->foo = $fooPayload->foo;
}
```

So essentially, I'm trying to deal with these 3 cases of possible `foo` values in PHP using type-safe way. I don't think this is the best (or most efficient) approach since I would need to use the reflection whenever I need to determine one of those 3 states of user input.

Do you know of any better way to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['payload'])){ $j = json_decode($_POST['payload']); if(isset($j->bar) && is_string($j->bar) && (isset($j->foo) && is_string($j->foo) || $j->foo === null)){ /* pass */ }else{ /* fail */ } }`